# Generating backreferences from a repeating group

Tags: regex

```
(?:\/(\w+?=\/)\/(\w+))*
```

Is there any way to retrieve backreferences from within a group? In my expression above does the no-reference (?:) prevent the entire group from capturing backreferences?

Trying to match for example:
/hello/how/are/you.../today and capture all the values between '/'

Comment: `\w` doesn't have to be surrounded by `[` `]`. And I'm pretty sure there should be an opening bracket before `?=` (with appropriate changes).

Comment: i added \w just to make it easier to read. edited to make it further easier to read thx

Comment: The quickest solution is to double the '/'

Comment: @BlackBear pardon my dundering but what do you mean?

Comment: I was also considering \G\/(\w+) but Im not even sure of how well supported \G is.

Comment: @MagicLassoI if you double the '//' so that you have '//hello///how//are//you//' the regex works as it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to retrieve backreferences from within a group?

Yes. Groups are not interpreted in a hierarchy. For example `(a(b))` has simply two groups, one and two, which can be (back)referenced. In terms of references it is equal to `(a)(b)`. The order of the references is simply determined by the order of the groups (determined by the start of the group) in the regex pattern. The fact that one group is part of another group does not change this fact.

> In my expression above does the no-reference (?:) prevent the entire group from capturing backreferences?

No. It only prevents the group marked as a non capture group from capturing (back)references. Nested  groups are unaffected and will be captured unless they, too, are marked as non capture groups.

Comment: Well it only took me a couple months to mark this but ty for the answer. Regex examples tend to be quite weak so anytime I run into something complicated its either a bunch of testing or stackoverflow.